# Using resources file

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using properties file in my java eclipse project. If I put these files in bin directory everything goes fine. But I don't like this solution, I would like to place them in separate folder called resources. But how to tell eclipse to use this resources directory?

Answer (score 1):

Right click the folder. Build path/Use as source folder

Comment: But in this case eclipse copies all resource directory to bin bolder during compilation and program doesn’t sees resource files. If it would copy these files to bin directly it would be ok

Comment: As I get it you want files to be under bin folder bin/file1.properties, bin/fil22.properties and you have them in resource directory in different structure like resources/folder1/file1.properties, resources/folder2/file2.properties. You have to add each folder* as a source folder into Java Build Path configuration.